# What is the name for 100 litres?

Tags: terminology, conventions, si-units, volume, metrology

- 1 litre = 1 litre
- 10 litres = decalitre
- 100 litres = ?
- 1000 litres = kilolitre

Is there a scale for the naming like there is for data?

Comment: If you are talking about oil - [Barrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_(unit)) ;)

Comment: Imperial is nuts lol

Comment: These are SI prefixes; full list can be found [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SIPrefixes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hectolitre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre#SI_prefixes_applied_to_the_litre)

See the linked Wikipedia page for all the prefixes.

Comment: Bangin thanks John!